# Cannot hit the getter of Property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am trying to use [AvalonDock](https://avalondock.codeplex.com) in Prism. All works fine except MenuItem "Tools->Properties". The MenuItem "File->New" works fine - new window is created and I can dock wherever I want.

This code works okay in simple MVVM application(without Prism) – “MenuItem” is fired always.

What I have:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ModuleCAvalonDock.ViewC">
<Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="New" Command="{Binding NewCommand}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Save" Command="{Binding ActiveDocument.SaveCommand}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Save As..." Command="{Binding ActiveDocument.SaveAsCommand}"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Close" Command="{Binding ActiveDocument.CloseCommand}"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Tools">
            <MenuItem Header="Properties" IsChecked="{Binding FileStats.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" IsCheckable="True"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Layout">
            <MenuItem Header="Load" Command="{Binding LoadLayoutCommand, ElementName=mainWindow}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Save" Command="{Binding SaveLayoutCommand, ElementName=mainWindow}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Dump to Console" Click="OnDumpToConsole"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</UserControl>
```

How I am binding:

```
public ViewC(IViewModel viewModel)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.DataContext = Workspace.This;
}
```

and ViewModel:

```
public class Workspace:ViewModelBase
{
   FileStatsViewModel _fileStats = null;
   public FileStatsViewModel FileStats
   {
      get
        {
          if (_fileStats == null)
             _fileStats = new FileStatsViewModel();
           return _fileStats;
        }
   }

   RelayCommand _newCommand = null;
    public ICommand NewCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_newCommand == null)
            {
                _newCommand = new RelayCommand((p) => OnNew(p), (p) => CanNew(p));
            }

            return _newCommand;
        }
    }

    private bool CanNew(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void OnNew(object parameter)
    {
        _files.Add(new FileViewModel());
        ActiveDocument = _files.Last();
    }


   protected Workspace()
    { 

    }

    static Workspace _this = new Workspace();

    public static Workspace This
    {
        get { return _this; }
    } 
}
```

FileStatsViewModel:

```
public class FileStatsViewModel : ToolViewModel {  }
public class ToolViewModel
{
    private bool _isVisible = true;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return _isVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (_isVisible != value)
            {
                _isVisible = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        }
     }
}
```

However, It does not work in Prism. I’ve tried setting some break point to check if the property is fired and FileStats property is firing  in simple MVVM application, but  FileStats property is not firing in Prism application!
The code where I initialize my View:

```
public class ModuleCModule: ModuleBase
{
    public ModuleCModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
            : base(container, regionManager) { }

    protected override void InitializeModule()
    {
        RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ContentRegion, typeof(ViewC));
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewC>();
    }
}
```

**It is really interesting that I can fire my command     `<MenuItem Header="New" Command="{Binding NewCommand}"/>`. However, I cannot fire property `FileStats` at viewModel `Workspace`.**

***How to fire my property? What am I doing wrong?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism has no impact on the WPF binding system, so this is an issue with how you are creating the binding to the DataContext of the view. How are you assigning the ViewModel to the DataContext of your View? Check your output window for binding errors. Chances are your DataContext is not being set.

If you are using the ViewModelLocator, then make sure you are following the proper naming conventions:

http://brianlagunas.com/getting-started-prisms-new-viewmodellocator/

**EDIT:**  I ran your app as is, and was able to hit the setter on your FileStats.IsVisible property.  If you are placing a breakpoint on the getter of FileStats, well that won't fire when you click on the menu item, because you are bound to a property of FileStats, not FileStats which is read-only anyways.  By the way, you know Prism 6.1 is out (you're using v4).  Also, you should try using NuGet instead of hard references.

Comment: It is really interesting that I can fire my command  <MenuItem Header="New" Command="{Binding NewCommand}"/>. However, I cannot fire property FileStats at viewModel Workspace.

Comment: See my updated answer.  Like I said, not a Prism issue :)

Comment: I am sorry, I've paste my original menu. Please, see my updated answer. Nevertheless, "Properties" does not fire "IsVisible" property. Please, help me. I've set breakpoint but breakpoint is not firing. uselessly.

Comment: Can you upload your sample to GitHub so that I can look at it in context to all your other code?  I copied and pasted everything you have as is, and it works fine for me.  There is something else going on in your project that I cannot see that could be causing this problem.

Comment: yeah, I've uploaded sample to GitHub:
https://github.com/NiceStepUp/HelloWorld
please, see

Comment: I am able to hit the setter at the start of program(F5 and hit the setter of IsVisible property). However, after the application is loaded and I click at "Tools->Properties", I cannot hit the setter of "IsVisible" property. Please, help me, Brian. 
 The most interesting thing is that if I run program without Prism I can hit getter of FileStats.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. The sample you provided works for me. I downloaded your app, clicked the Tools->Properties button multiple times, and the breakpoint hit every time and the value updated every time.  This is not a prism problem, actually I don't see a problem.  I will say that your app architecture is a mess, but I assume this is just a test app, so I'm not rally going to beat you up over it :)

Comment: wow, have you seen a TreeView(Nodes 1,2,3,4,5) and <TextBox Text="test"/> after clicking Tools-Properties? This appl is from QuickStart of Prism v4.0 and I use this appl to show a problem.

Comment: The only change I made was to comment out the creation of the BitmapImage in the constructor of the FileStatsViewModel because it was throwing an exception.

Comment: Brian, you are the master!!!!! You are the etalon! Thank you very much! I cannot figured out for two days!!! Thanks a lot!